# how get count from mongodb with different status from one collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have appointment collection in that i have status codes like upcoming, cancelled, completed. i want to write an api to get count of each status using mongoose or mongodb methods.

output should be like below

```
[{
    group : "grp1",
    appointments_completed :4
    appointments_upcoming :5
    appointments_cancelled : 7
}]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want make one request or several is good too?

Comment: Provide some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope it help you

```
db.getCollection('codelist').aggregate([
{
    $group:{
    _id:{status:"$status"},
    count:{$sum:1}
    } 
}
])
```

The result will be

```
[{
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "cancelled"
    },
    "count" : 13.0
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "status" : "completed"
    },
    "count" : 20.0
}

]
```

I think you can process it with nodejs

Comment: `$status` is not an attribute in the collection, it is having different status such as completed, upcoming and cancelled.

Comment: you didn't show data example, that is why I think you have attribute status.

Comment: thank u so much for your answer Evgeniy . its working fine for me . thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Using [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) we can get this count

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ 
   { $group: { 
       _id:null, 
       appointments_completed: {$sum : "$appointments_completed" }, 
       appointments_upcoming:{$sum :"$appointments_upcoming"}, 
       appointments_cancelled:{$sum: "$appointments_cancelled"}
      }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDb 3.6 and newer, you can leverage the use of **[`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)** operator and a **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** pipeline to get the desired result. You would need to run the following aggregate pipeline:

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {  
            "group": <group_by_field>,
            "status": { "$concat": ["appointments_", { "$toLower": "$status" }] }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.group",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "k": "$_id.status",
                "v": "$count"
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "counts": {
            "$setUnion": [
                "$counts", [
                    {
                        "k": "group",
                        "v": "$_id"
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    } },
    {  "$replaceRoot": {
        "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
    } }    
])
```

---

For older versions, a more generic approach though with a different output format would be to group twice and get the counts as an array of key value objects as in the following:

```
db.appointments.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "group": <group_by_field>,
            "status": { "$toLower": "$status" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.group",
        "counts": {
            "$push": {
                "status": "$_id.status",
                "count": "$count"
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

which spits out:

```
{
    "_id": "grp1"
    "counts":[
        { "status": "completed", "count": 4 },
        { "status": "upcoming", "count": 5 }
        { "status": "cancelled", "count": 7 }
    ]
}
```

If the status codes are fixed then the [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) operator in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) pipeline step can be used effectively to evaluate the counts based on the status field value. Your overall aggregation pipeline can be constructed as follows to produce the result in the desired format:

```
db.appointments.aggregate([    
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": <group_by_field>,             
        "appointments_completed": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "completed" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "appointments_upcoming": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "upcoming" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        },
        "appointments_cancelled": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ { "$eq": [ "$status", "cancelled" ] }, 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

---